# expr is not an Linux builtin command,why expr $BASHPID show current shell pid

Tags: linux, bash, shell

expr is not an Linux builtin command,why expr $BASHPID show current shell pid?

It's so strange! I think it should output subshell pid.

```
$ type expr
expr is hashed (/usr/bin/expr)
$ echo $$
49207
$ expr $BASHPID
49207
```

Comment: `foo $bar` expands `$bar` **before** `foo` starts. So `expr $BASHPID` is just running `expr 49207`; the `expr` command has no control over how the expansion is performed.

Comment: Beyond that, because `$BASHPID` is a shell variable, external commands don't have a `BASHPID` value at all, unless they themselves are implemented in bash, and even then you'd need to do extra work to both (1) defer evaluation until the command is started, and (2) force evaluation _after_ the command is started.

Comment: Also, please provide transcripts demonstrating your problem **inside the text of the question, not as screenshots**. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122); content that only exists in a screenshot or link is not considered "in the question itself" for purposes of compliance with [mre] rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal and expected: *Parameter expansion happens before command execution*, so `BASHPID` tells you the PID of the instance of bash that's determining which arguments to pass to `expr`, not the PID of `expr` itself. By the time a `fork()` takes place, these arguments are already determined.

If you want the PID of expr itself, you can use an explicit subshell to make the fork happen earlier, and then use `exec` to make `expr` inherit that subshell's PID:

```
echo "Parent PID is $$ / $BASHPID"
(printf %s 'expr PID is '; exec expr "$BASHPID")
```

The `(` creates an explicit subshell (instead of the implicit one created during the execution process), so `BASHPID` then provides its PID; `exec` causes `expr` to inherit that PID.